# Voice command will not open activity

Tags: android, speech-recognition

I am trying to put together a voice controlled app, having gone through a number of examples etc I have the following code.

```
        FloatingActionButton fab = findViewById(R.id.fab);
    fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Intent intent = new  Intent(RecognizerIntent.ACTION_RECOGNIZE_SPEECH);
            intent.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_LANGUAGE_MODEL,
                    RecognizerIntent.LANGUAGE_MODEL_FREE_FORM);
            intent.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_MAX_RESULTS, 1);
            mySpeechRecognizer.startListening(intent);
            speak("I wait for your instuctions");
        }
    });
```

and

```
                @Override
            public void onResults(Bundle bundle) {
                List<String> results = bundle.getStringArrayList(
                        SpeechRecognizer.RESULTS_RECOGNITION
                );
                processResult(results.get(0));


            }
```

with

```
    private void processResult(String mycom){
    mycom = mycom.toLowerCase();

    if(mycom.contains("one")) {
        speak("Opening one");
        Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, OneActivity.class);
        startActivity(intent);
```

The app builds and runs with the app saying "I wait for your instuctions" but does not open the new activity after instruction from user.

Can someone help in helping me to understand where I have got it wrong.

Comment: what is 'mySpeechRecognizer' and 'speak' function's instructions in your code?

Comment: private SpeechRecognizer mySpeechRecognizer; and speak is the output from app not the user.